# switching icon in a button with jquery

Tags: jquery, click

creating a sliding top menu bar with a button and trying to switch button icon when click, default is angle up and its changed to angle down when click and back up so on.

so it's not happening with html function

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
    type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
    type="text/css">


<style type="text/css">
    header{position: relative;}
    .headerPrimary{min-height: 40px; background: black; color: white; padding: 20px 5px; width: 100%;}
    .headerSecondry{min-height: 100px; background: grey; color: black; padding: 20px 5px; width: 100%; }
    .closeDip{position: absolute; padding: 10px 5px; background: red; width: 50px; height: 30px; bottom: -30px; left: 100px; border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px; cursor: pointer;}

</style>


</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="headerPrimary"></div>
        <div class="headerSecondry"></div>
        <div class="closeDip"></div>
    </header>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(e){
        $(".closeDip").html('<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></>');
        $(".closeDip").click(function(){
            $(".headerSecondry").slideToggle(function(){
                $(".closeDip").html('<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></>');
            }).click(function(){
                $(".closeDip").html('<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></>');
            });
        });
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(".closeDip").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".headerSecondry").slideToggle(function(){
        var icon = $this.find('.fa').hasClass('fa-angle-up') ? '<i class="fa fa-angle-down">' : '<i class="fa fa-angle-up">';
                //-------------^---missed it.
        $this.html(icon);
    });
});
```

In the `.slideToggle()` method you can toggle the icon with a check if the contained element has the class name `fa-angle-up` as you have appended it at doc ready.

```js
$(".closeDip").html('<i class="fa fa-angle-up">[+]</i>');
$(".closeDip").click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $(".headerSecondry").slideToggle(function() {
        var icon = $this.find('.fa').hasClass('fa-angle-up') ? '<i class="fa fa-angle-down">[-]</i>' : '<i class="fa fa-angle-up">[+]</i>';
        $this.html(icon);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='headerSecondry'>headerSecondry</div>
<div class="closeDip">[+]</div>
```

Comment: no its not working, by default its adding angle-up and then its not toggling the icon,

Comment: @PratyushGoyal there was a typo in the code `.find('.fa')` i missed a dot here. you see a sample demo also i have added.